# Dynamically editing a movieclip at runtime

Tags: 2d, flash, actionscript-3, game-mechanics

I am trying to make a flash game(actionScript-3 if it matters) to test what I learned so far. And, in the game, I want to make the character(a robot?) customizable. The first solution I found was to edit the character movieclip directy. Is it possible to edit a movieclip at runtime? If yes, how?

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do, could you give an example to make it more clear? You can go to specific frames of a movieclip using [gotoAndStop(frame)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001310.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try using multiple movieclips (for the head, body, legs etc). That way you can switch them out easily. Put them together in a Sprite container.